# Apply z-index to div overflow (scrollbar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with horizontal scrollbar and an image (or other div) over entire page (with position absolute). The prolem is I want to be able to scroll the div which is beside the image. For `a` links I positioned them relative and applied z-index. **How can I apply `z-index` only for div's scrollbar? So, I want the div to be behind the image.**

**Screenshoot Example:**

[image: Black lines are an image with position absolute over the page.]

**Visual Example:**

```html
<div style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; width: 300px; height: 130px; white-space: nowrap;">
            s sd ds fsd fs df s fs fds fsd fsd fsd fds f sdf sd fs fsd f sdf sd f sdf sd f sdf ds fsdf sf ds f sdf dsf sdf s df sdf sdf ds fsd fsdf sd fds 
            <br/>fsd fds f sd fsd fsd fds fs df sd f sd fds f sd f sdf sd f ds fsdf s df sd fs df sdfsd f 
            <br/>sdf ds f sdf sd f dsf sd fds f ds fs df sd fds f ds f sd fs df sd fsdfs df sdf sd fs df sd fsd 
            <br/>sdf ds f sdf sd f dsf sd fds f ds fs df sd fds f ds f sd fs df sd fsdfs df sdf sd fs df sd fsd 
            <br/>sdf ds f sdf sd f dsf sd fds f ds fs df sd fds f ds f sd fs df sd fsdfs df sdf sd fs df sd fsd 
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <img src="http://www.wabmo.com/Album/watermark/watermarks/Sample-trans.png" width="300"/>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `z-index` is not working here. There is no way to hide the div from the scrollbar with position `absolute` or `fixed`. You have to do other workarounds, like setting the height of the div inside, or calculate the scrollbar height and reduce it with JS, ...

Comment: You want to that image over the div?? or i can place the image below the div

Comment: @Yuva I said: "How can I apply z-index only for div's scrollbar?". So, I want the div to be behind the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `pointer-events:none` to another div which consist of `img` tag.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;pointer-events:none;">
            <img src="http://www.wabmo.com/Album/watermark/watermarks/Sample-trans.png" width="300;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yuvakom/nztso6kh/) helpful for you

```
.sample
    {
      position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;pointer-events:none;
    }
    
    <div style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; width: 300px; height: 130px; white-space: nowrap; ">
                s sd ds fsd fs df s fs fds fsd fsd fsd fds f sdf sd fs fsd f sdf sd f sdf sd f sdf ds fsdf sf ds f sdf dsf sdf s df sdf sdf ds fsd fsdf sd fds 
                <br/>fsd fds f sd fsd fsd fds fs df sd f sd fds f sd f sdf sd f ds fsdf s df sd fs df sdfsd f 
                <br/>sdf ds f sdf sd f dsf sd fds f ds fs df sd fds f ds f sd fs df sd fsdfs df sdf sd fs df sd fsd 
                <br/>sdf ds f sdf sd f dsf sd fds f ds fs df sd fds f ds f sd fs df sd fsdfs df sdf sd fs df sd fsd 
                <br/>sdf ds f sdf sd f dsf sd fds f ds fs df sd fds f ds f sd fs df sd fsdfs df sdf sd fs df sd fsd 
    </div>
    <div class='sample'>
                <img src="http://www.wabmo.com/Album/watermark/watermarks/Sample-trans.png" width="300"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for text content div

```
 z-index: 100;
 position: relative;
```

Demo link https://jsfiddle.net/m5p5ngep/2/

Comment: I said: "How can I apply z-index only for div's scrollbar?". So, I want the div to be behind the image. Thank you!

Comment: you can put z-index in minus value see the example https://jsfiddle.net/m5p5ngep/3/

Comment: Hilarity ensues when you try to use the scrollbars. :-P Scrollbars don't work.